# Has this "mean like" method any known name?

Tags: terminology

Lets say you've a min and a max value, and based on a percent value, you get the equivalent value, for example:

- min=10, max=30, perc=50% -> value=20
- min=10, max=30, perc=10% -> value=12

Is it known by any specific name?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical name for what you're talking about is [Linear Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) - though I've on rare occasions seen it called the 'of-the-way' function; e.g. '10% of the way from 10 to 30'.  As you might guess from the name, there are other ways of interpolating between 'start' (your minimum) and 'finish' (your maximum - note that you could always go the other way, from 30 to 10!) values; [Spline Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) is another very frequent one, often in the form of 'ease-in, ease-out' curves.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is a very simple form of [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).